# How to convert this PHP curl command into JS

Tags: javascript, php, http

I am trying to reverse engineer some php code and then run it in JS. The php code is as follows:

```
$fields_string = '';
    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //decode result;
    $data = json_decode($result, TRUE);
    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
```

I am using axios in JS and currently trying the following:

```
const response: any = await axios.post(base_url, 'key1=value1&key2=value2', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
        }
    });
```

But I seem to be getting issues as the server isn't able to parse the body correctly. I was wondering if anyone had any tips for what it should look like instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send form-data with axios you should pass `FormData` obj as data, it will change to the proper header.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key1', 'value1');
formData.append('key2', 'value2');

const response = await axios.post(base_url, formData);
```